# The 'this' pointer in the initialization list of the constructor

Tags: c++, syntax-error, this, language-lawyer, ctor-initializer

I guess I am unable to understand why this is not working. I always thought that I can use '`this`' pointer inside the constructor, but I never knew that I cannot use '`this`' in the initialization list.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        A(int a = 0, int b = 0) : this->a(a), this->b(b) { }
        void print() {
        std::cout << a << ", " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.print();
}
```

I am interested to know the details related to it.

Comment: I've tagged "language lawyer": I'm not convinced my answer is correct.

Comment: You're not inside the body of the constructor though, you're in the initializer list of the constructor.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `b(this->a)` would be just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the question! Saved my time!

Answer (score 38):

Simply because there's no need, an initializer list can already disambiguate because its syntax is strict:

```
member(value)
```

So you can just change it to:

```
A(int a = 0, int b = 0) : a(a), b(b) {}
```

`this->member` is only really used when the programmer needs to help the compiler to disambiguate, for example, if your constructor would've looked like:

```
A(int a = 0, int b = 0) 
{ 
  // set local 'a' to itself
  a = a; 
}
```

Your `A::a` wouldn't have been initialized now, oops!

You would need `this` to help the compiler:

```
A(int a = 0, int b = 0) 
{ 
  this->a = a; // set A::a to local a.
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that using `this` to access members when ambiguity is an issue is more of a Java thing. In C++, your attributes should (usually) have a name like `a_`, which reduces the above line to `a_ = a;`. To quote the [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_Names): _Data members of classes (but not structs) additionally have trailing underscores._

Comment: @KonstantinĐ.: Note that the Google C++ Style Guide is not well-respected among C++ programmers, and should not be taken as representative of what the C++ community recommends.

Comment: @KonstantinĐ. The value of prefix/suffix naming conventions are very subjective, and often unnecessary. That's why the `this` construct exist in the first place. I would recommend Clean Code by Bob Martin for a different perspective.

Answer (score 31):

`this->a` is grammatically invalid because it is a member-access expression, but only an identifier is allowed there (or a type specifier, for base classes).

From the C++ standard, [class.base.init],

> *mem-initializer-id:*
>         *class-or-decltype*
>         *identifier*

Comment: Right, and the "why" is .... because there would be absolutely no need to complicate the grammar to allow an added `this->`. In fact you'd then have to backtrack with a bunch of "... is ill-formed" rules to ban basically anything you'd just added _but_ the added `this->`.